# Singleton class Identification

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Can anyone please tell me whether this is a singleton class or not?

```
public class Final_output{

  Cafe_factory obj=null;

  private Final_output()
  {
    obj = new Cafe_factory();
    obj.getOrder("French Fries");
    obj.getOrder("Biryani");
    obj.getOrder("Ice-cream");
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new Final_output();
  }
}
```

`Cafe_factory` is another class in the same package.

Comment: This is not a singleton.. It just any other normal Standalone class

Comment: As a side note, it is [standard convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) to use TitleCase (no underscores) for Java class names.

Comment: Isn't the singleton pattern an anti pattern in the Java world (honest question)?

Comment: @PeeHaa I think there's a time and a place for it. It's probably one of the patterns that's most often used when it shouldn't be, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Singleton for Example is:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how will you create a singleton class Final_output which can create the object of class Cafe_factory and call its(cafe_factory) function by using the same object.

Comment: See also Joshua Bloch's `enum` singleton pattern (Effective Java 2nd edition, Item 3, or [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3)).

Comment: You need to Implement cafe_factory as Singleton or Final_output, in your case eachtime you call new Final_output(); you create an instanz of it which creates a new instance of cafe_factory.

Answer (score 2):

Not, it's not. Because you can't create instances of this class outside of it (at least one instance should exist). For the other hand - you can create as many instances inside `main` as you wish (so it's not singleton either).

Here is an example of Singleton:

```
public class MySingleton{
    private MySingleton(){}

    private static InstanceHolder{
        private static final MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance(){
        return InstanceHolder.instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not.

A singleton has as objective to limit to 1 the number of instances of the same class that can be created, and provide static methods to retrieve this instance.

This is typically done via a private constructor and static methods to retrieve this unique instance. Here neither `Final_output` nor `Cafe_factory` respect this contract so none of them use the singleton pattern.

Comment: According to your explanation - his class **is** singleton :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you could create n amount of new Cafe_Factory objects in your code also outside the Final_output class, no it is not a singleton. A singleton is never created with the new keyword. Instead, you fetch an instance of it via a static method.

Answer (score 0):

this :

```
public class Final_output{

    private static Cafe_factory obj = null;

    private Final_output()
    {
       obj = getCafeInstance();
    }

    public static getCafeInstance(){
        if(null == obj){
             obj = new Cafe_factory();
             obj.getOrder("French Fries");
             obj.getOrder("Biryani");
             obj.getOrder("Ice-cream");
           }else{
               return obj;
           }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

NO This is not a singleTon

```
public class Final_output{
   private static Final_output ourInstance = new Final_output();
   Cafe_factory obj=null;    

   private Final_output() {
     obj = new Cafe_factory();
     obj.getOrder("French Fries");
     obj.getOrder("Biryani");
     obj.getOrder("Ice-cream");
   }

   public Final_output getINstance(){
       return ourInstance;
   }

}
```

Comment: And why did you copied his question?

Comment: And now it's even worse :) Look closely to your `getINstance()`.

Comment: Still broken... your `getINstance` (sic) should return `ourInstance`. Maybe best just deleting this answer?

Comment: getInstance() should be static.